# "we both of our know" or "both of us know"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one is correct?:

> we both of our know....

or

> both of us know.....

Can I say "we both of know"?

> We both of know which class we are studying

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! I have fixed the formatting for you. Take a look. If there's anything else you need to add feel free to [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/266876/edit) your question.

Comment: Only "both of us know..." of all of these is correct. You can also say, "we both know..."